# Plotly Tick Format - Milliseconds to HH:MM

Tags: time, axis-labels, milliseconds, plotly.js

I've the below PlotlyJS chart which is made with the code below. I have a function which loops through a list of a chronological events (in this case it's sunrise, set and twilights). It creates sub lists which are the start and duration of each event for a specific day in milliseconds. The x axis at present shows milliseconds and the traces are displaying correctly.

My question is how to format the ticklabels so that they are not in the millions but instead in HH:MM format?

I've had a look [here](https://plotly.com/javascript/tick-formatting/) on the Plotly site about tick formatting but nothing seems to fit my need!

[image: Example Chart]

each trace is built with the below:

```
          var trace =  {x: [duration],
                        base: start,
                        y: [startDate.format('DD-MM-YY')],
                        orientation: 'h',
                        marker: { color: solarEventColors[sunStatus[i+1]], width: 1},
                        type: 'bar',
                        opacity: 0.5,
                        }
          dataArray.push(trace)
```

The layout used for the PlotlyJS chart is:

```
var layoutSunChart = {title: 'Solar Events by Time',
                        barmode: 'relative',
                        bargroupgap: 0.4,
                        yaxis: {type: 'category',
                        autorange: "reversed",
                                fixedrange: true, 
                                showgrid : false,
                                automargin: true,
                                    },
                        xaxis : {

                           tickmode: "linear",
                                tick0: 0,
                                dtick: 8640000, // milliseconds
                                fixedrange: true, 
                                zeroline : false, 
                                showgrid : false,
                                automargin: true,
                                title: 'Time (hh:mm)'
                            },
                        autosize: true,
                        showlegend: false,
                        paper_bgcolor: '#E9ECEF',
                        plot_bgcolor:'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                        //hovermode: 'closest',
                        staticPlot: true,
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you've mistaken the axis x and y. but if I got it right you want to show miliseconds? So you need to use one of the two following tickformat:

`tickformat: '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f`, to show just the significative numbers (at least .0 if none milisecond is given)

or

`tickformat: '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%L'`, to show all the miliseconds (even .000)

But if you want to show all the number you can put `.f` in it tickformat. Something like this:

`tickformat: '.3f'`

This way, you'll show 3 decimal places, for example.